Prove that a maximal edge independent set is a maximum edge independent set if and only if it is a subset of some minimum edge cover.
Prove that a maximal edge independent set is a maximum edge independent set if and only if it is a subset of some minimum edge cover.
Below is my try. If a maximal edge independent set is a maximum edge, then according to the definition of the maximum edge independent set, it is also a minimum edge cover because if we add any edge that is not belong to the maximal edge independent set into this set, then we get two edges adjacent. But another orientation is difficult for me. If this maximal independent set is a subset of some minimum edge cover, then is it a maximum edge?

A maximum edge independent set is not, itself, a minimum edge cover. An edge cover does not need to be independent, but it should include every vertex, which a maximum edge independent set often won't. (Also, terminology-wise: you should not abbreviate "maximum edge independent set" to "maximum edge" because that's incomprehensible, but you might well say "maximum matching" because that is what most people call them.)
